# Why do I get error in Python- Pandas, AttributeError:: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'unique'?

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

I have some code to convert all columns of my DataFrame of type 'object' to type 'category'.  I'm just looping through my DF by column, which has already been filtered to object types, and getting those with low ratio of unique values to just convert those.

```
converted_obj = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df201911_obj.columns:
    num_unique_values = len(df201911_obj[col].unique())
    num_total_values = len(df201911_obj[col])
    if num_unique_values / num_total_values < 0.5:
        converted_obj.loc[:,col] = df201911_obj[col].astype('category')
    else:
        converted_obj.loc[:,col] = df201911_obj[col]
```

I am getting an AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'unique'

I checked all the data type of the columns with a loop, since there are over 100 columns:

```
for col in df201911_obj.columns:
    print(type(col))
```

And they are all: `<class 'str'>`

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Do you have repeated column names?

Comment: I sure did.  @Quang Hoang

Comment: `df[some_dup_col_name]` gives you a dataframe, not series, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

On Attibute error, try reloading all your libraries first, then reload all your predifined variables or other dataframes in your system, then just delete the code part that is causing the problem and rewrite the code(This fixes any syntax error if any).
I tried the above fix and it worked on
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dublicated'`
I was using google colabs, and the problem was with loading the dataframe